# How to order SQLite database alphabetically

Tags: javascript, mysql

I have a SQLite database in French with utf-8 encoding and am trying to organize my categories in alphabetical order. My setup currently looks like: https://i.stack.imgur.com/LmDTV.png

I tried to add `SELECT DISTINCT Category FROM 'Main Database' ORDER BY name` but unfortunately it did not display correctly. Can anyone tell me the correct way to alphabetize my `Category` column in ABC order?

Javascript:

```
function onDeviceReady() {
if (window.device.platform === 'iOS' && parseFloat(window.device.version) >= 7.0)        
        StatusBar.overlaysWebView(false);
db = window.sqlitePlugin.openDatabase({name: "treatfinder", bgType: 1});
db.transaction(function(tx){
               tx.executeSql("SELECT DISTINCT Category FROM 'Main Database'",[],function(tx,res){
                             //console.log("Number of Categories: " + res.rows.length);
                             var len = res.rows.length;
                             for (var i=0; i < len; i = i + 1) {
                                 $("#allRepos").append("<li><a href='treatsymptoms.html?category=" + res.rows.item(i).Category + "'>"
                                                       + res.rows.item(i).Category + "</a></li>");

                             }
                             $('#allRepos').listview('refresh');

                             });                                            
               })
```

Comment: ``B`Y after ``? Huh? you mean "order by"?

Comment: That is correct. When I do this, nothing displays on the front-end.

Comment: well, yea, it's `order by name`. `by name` is just a syntax error.

Comment: I tried both ORDER BY and BY but unfortunately neither does not display my categories when added.